# How to use layout bigger than tablet screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm creating an app which I will use a layout like this

[image: Imagem Layout 1]

Black - Tablet Screen | Purple - Menu | Light Blue - ListView 1 | Blue - Content | Red - ListView 2

And after I choose an option from Listview 1, my layout needs to be like this another image

[image: Imagem Layout 2]

Black - Tablet Screen | Purple - Menu | Light Blue - ListView 1 | Blue - Content | Red - ListView 2

So, how I create my layout bigger than tablet screen (using XML) and just do something that will hide/show Listview 1 or Listview 2 to work using any tablet?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Include both `ListView` in your XML (I'll assume you use `left_list` and `right_list` for IDs), preferably in a `LinearLayout` with your content view and the content view has `layout_weight="1"`
2. Add `android:visibility='gone'` to your XML for `right_list`
3. Ensure you have a reference to `left_list` and `right_list` in your `Activity` (I'll assume these are `leftList` and `rightList`
4. When clicking a list item, call `leftList.setVisibility(View.GONE); rightList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to trigger the visibility to change.

Comment: Right @ianhanniballake. It's working. Thanks.
Now I'm using a adapter in my left list.
How I call the right list (who is in the main class) to show if the declaration of my buttons (who will be in the left list) is in my adapter class?

Comment: @groff07 - I'd suggest looking at `ListView`'s `setOnItemClickListener` method and see if that works for you. Otherwise, you'll need to look into providing a callback interface to pass click events from your adapter to your activity. If you're still having issues, submit another question with more details and the code you are trying to get working.

Comment: I will try something like that and come back later to say.
If I cannot make it work I will open a new question with my code and mark you so you can look and help me? Can be?

Comment: @groff07 - as with any new question, there's bound to be many people looking at it, but feel free to leave a link to the new question here if you wish. Best of luck!